# What are the benefits of enabling mTLS in Istio?

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, istio

I try to understand why [Istio](https://istio.io) have the mTLS feature? It enables mutual TLS authentication between all the services in a cluster via automatically issued certificates.

Mandatory TLS authentication is a benefit only as long as they are services outside Istio, but when Istio is enabled globally in Kubernetes, this is not the case - then every service gets certificate automatically, so can connect to any other.

Maybe TLS is used as identity provider, required by Istio authorization rules, like asked in yet unanswered [Does istio authorization have effect if mtls is not used for istio authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55071965/does-istio-authorization-have-effect-if-mtls-is-not-used-for-istio-authenticatio)? But why Istio does not just use Kubernetes service accounts as identity provider. This is even mentioned in [documentation](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#istio-identity).

Also, even with TLS for identity, why encrypting traffic (TLS can be used without encryption)? I am assuming here that the container is not able to spoof IP address.

Comment: Mutual TLS enables secure connections between containers without having to manually issue certificates and/or distribute them. One nice aspect of this is **TLS origination** for HTTP services (this [example](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/mutual-tls/#verify-mutual-tls-configuration) illustrates the point pretty well). Also, TLS connections inside the cluster are recommended in the [the Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/securing-a-cluster/#use-transport-level-security-tls-for-all-api-traffic) for added security.